# microsoft-graph Azure AD signIns preview log modification

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I tried to run the sign-in report for all our azure accounts, I went to Azure AD and-> Sign-Ins -> download, downloaded the PowerShell scripts and successful get the data. However, it generated too much detail. 
URL =  `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns`?

I ran for past 7 days and generated over 100M txt data, I am just looking for signIns report for all users with id and createdDateTime only.

How can I can change the export data? I am new for this Graph Explorer, please let me know if you have any idea and suggestion, thank you.

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#auditLogs/signIns",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-11-20T00:12:09.3961159Z",
            "userDisplayName": "",
            "userPrincipalName": ".com",
            "userId": "",
            "appId": "",
            "appDisplayName": "Graph explorer",
            "ipAddress": "",
            "clientAppUsed": "Browser",
            "mfaDetail": null,
            "correlationId": "",
            "conditionalAccessStatus": null,
            "originalRequestId": null,
            "isInteractive": true,
            "tokenIssuerName": null,
            "tokenIssuerType": "AzureAD",
            "processingTimeInMilliseconds": 0,
            "riskDetail": "hidden",
            "riskLevelAggregated": "hidden",
            "riskLevelDuringSignIn": "hidden",
            "riskState": "none",
            "riskEventTypes": [],
            "resourceDisplayName": "microsoft graph",
            "resourceId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "authenticationMethodsUsed": [],

}
```

[image]

Comment: Done, thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

> I am just looking for signIns report for all users with id and
>   createdDateTime only

In the Microsoft Graph Api, the query `$select=id,createdDateTime` could make you wanted, but **signIns** not support `select`, and others [supported query](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/signin_list) cannot make this. 
[image]

Comment: Therefore, i have no way to generate the report with smaller data?

Comment: I already tried other ways, but cannot make it as you wanted. Later if there is a new method, I will update here.